# Arrange list for display

Tags: python, list

I would like to arrange the following structure by sorting each column and adding space if needed. Structure integrity should be maintained.

Here is the structure used:

[image]

What would be the best approach to solve this?

- Build line per line a new list by taking max value(s) each time ?
- Keep an index for each column and browsing through?
- Or is there a more "pythonic" way to solve this?

Thanks in advance for your insights.

**Edit**: expected in/outputs:

```
din = [['96.3', '90.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
      ['105.6', '104.4', '102.8', '101.5', '100.3', '96.3', '93.2', '90.0', '', '', ''], 
      ['98.35', '90.09', '81.07', '75.76', '65.1', '56.56', '50.02', '43.69', '36.61', '29.29', '24.0'], 
      ['94.02', '63.89', '43.69', '24.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]

dout = [[''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,'96.3',''    ,''     ,'90.0',''     ,''     ,''    ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''], 
        ['105.6','104.4','102.8','101.5','100.3',''     ,''     ,'96.3','93.2',''     ,'90.0',''     ,''     ,''    ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''],
        [''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,'98.35',''     ,''    ,''    ,'90.09',''    ,'81.07','75.76','65.1',''     ,'56.56','50.02','43.69','36.61','29.29','24.0'], 
        [''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,''     ,'94.02',''    ,''    ,''     ,''    ,''     ,''     ,''    ,'63.89',''     ,''     ,'43.69',''     ,''     ,'24.0']]
```

[image]

EDIT2: I ended up by going through each column, find the max and insert empty field when it was not the max value found.

This approach gave me the wanted results.

```py
    j=0
    m = len(din[0])
    lastRow = 0
    # Stop when index reach shortest column length
    while j < m and len(din)>1:
        # get max value for each line
        maxI = max([float(_[j]) for _ in din if _[j]!='']) 
        
        # go through all timeframe
        for i in range(0,len(din)):
            # only keep the biggest, insert empty string otherwise
            if din[i][j] == '':
                din[i].insert(j,'')
            elif float(din[i][j]) < maxI:
                din[i].insert(j,'')
            else:
                lastRow=j
        # find the shortest column
        m = min([len(_) for _ in din])
        j += 1

    # Crop columns
    output=[]
    if len(din)>1:
        for _ in din:
            output.append(_[:lastRow+1])
    else:
        output = din
```

Comment: Can you give us your input and desired output please? You've illustrated the structure you want as output, but not what you have to start with.

Comment: I just updated first post ;)

Comment: Have you decided on an approache and solved this? If so, please share your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I had to assume the OP's desired output swapped the columns for '96.3' and '94.02'. If that assumption is correct, I offer the following solution without any claims that it is pythonic, optimal or even that it addresses the OP's question directly.

It simply works.

```
import numpy as np

din = [['96.3', '90.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ['105.6', '104.4', '102.8', '101.5', '100.3', '96.3', '93.2', '90.0', '', '', ''],
    ['98.35', '90.09', '81.07', '75.76', '65.1', '56.56', '50.02', '43.69', '36.61', '29.29', '24.0'],
    ['94.02', '63.89', '43.69', '24.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]

arr = np.array(din)  # We'll use numpy

# Let's work with numeric data.
to_float = lambda x: None if x=='' else float(x)
vfunc = np.vectorize(to_float)
numeric_in = vfunc(arr)

# Find unique values in decending order
arr = np.hstack(numeric_in)  # One-dimentional array
arr = arr[np.logical_not(np.isnan(arr))]  # Drop the nan's
arr = np.unique(arr)  #  Naturally
unique = np.flip(arr)  #  Descending order
length = len(unique)  #  Count the unique values -> width of dout.

# Let's build an output (str) array of size 4 x length.
dout = np.array(['DEFAULT'] * length * 4, dtype=str)
dout = np.reshape(dout, (4,length))

# ... and populate it with the required values at the right places
for i, row in enumerate(numeric_in):
    for x in row:
        if not np.isnan(x):
            idx = np.where(unique == x)[0][0]
            dout[i,idx] = x

dout[dout == 'DEFAULT'] = '' # Set the 'DEFAULT' values to ''
print(dout)
```

Which output this:

```
[['' '' '' '' '' '' '96.3' '' '' '' '90.0' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['105.6' '104.4' '102.8' '101.5' '100.3' '' '96.3' '' '93.2' '' '90.0'
  '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '98.35' '' '' '' '90.09' '' '81.07' '75.76' '65.1' ''
  '56.56' '50.02' '43.69' '36.61' '29.29' '24.0']
 ['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '94.02' '' '' '' '' '' '' '63.89' '' '' '43.69' ''
  '' '24.0']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution !
In the meantime, I ended up with another approach (see first post), which consisted at adding empty string when it was not the biggest of a column.
This worked as intended as well.